# Input method in class

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Class Gui: # будущее гуи, получает данные о спортсмене
    # и передает в класс Person

    def input(self):
        self.inputName =input("name")
        return self.inputName

the_app=Gui() 
print the_app.input()
```

How to decide my problem?

Please help
now, i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/home/julia/COURSEWORK/person.py", line 34, in <module>
     print the_app.input()   
File "/home/julia/COURSEWORK/person.py", line 29, in input
     self.inputName =input("name")   
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Comment: Use `raw_input()`, not `input()` in Python 2.

Comment: `File "", line 1, in NameError: name 'j' is not defined` I don't see 'j' anywhere in the above.

Comment: @cgeroux: that's because she typed it as input, and `input()` tried to `eval()` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.x, [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) evaluates its input as real Python code.  In other words, it is equivalent to this:

```
eval(raw_input())
```

To fix the error you showed, you need to use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead, which does not evaluate its input but returns it as a string object.

---

Also, Python is case-sensitive.  Moreover, all keywords, including `class`, are lowercase.  So, when you run that code, you will get a `NameError` saying that `Class` is undefined (I don't know how you got to the point you did without encountering this.  Perhaps you made a typo when posting here?)

---

Finally, in Python 2.x, all classes should inherit from the [`object`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#object) built-in in order to make them "new style" classes.  You can read about those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/2555451).

---

All in all, your code should look like this:

```
class Gui(object): # будущее гуи, получает данные о спортсмене
    # и передает в класс Person

    def input(self):
        self.inputName = raw_input("name")
        return self.inputName

the_app = Gui() 
print the_app.input()
```